# Switches in Java

Tags: java, string, variables, switch-statement

I was practicing the other day and I came accross this error with a string for a switch:

```
Cannot switch on a value of type String. Only int values or enum constants are permitted
```

I'm not sure how I would fix this so I came here for help. I am using Eclipse. Here is the source, the second VARIABLE (in caps) is where I get the error:

```
public class Switch {
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Please enter a command: ");
    String VARIABLE = input.nextLine();

    switch (VARIABLE) {
    case "start":
        System.out.println("Machine started!");
        break;

    case "stop":
        System.out.println("Machine stopped!");
        break;

    default:
        System.out.println("Invalid command");
    }

}
}
```

It'd be cool if someone can help me with this. I'm relatively new to this so I'm not sure if any of this even makes sense.

Comment: It means exactly what is says; you can't switch on a String. Java 7 adds this ability and the docs/tutorial state this: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/switch.html

Comment: What is the output of `java -version`?

Comment: It means its now time to upgrade to Java 1.7

Comment: You could use enums to codify your commands.  Then add a method to your enum to take a string and return the corresponding enum or null if the command is unrecognized.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
switch (VARIABLE) {
```

`switch` with `Strings` are supported from Java 7 onwards. I guess you are using lower version of java you need to either upgrade your java version to 7 (or) remove String from switch and use supported types.

Here is [oracle tutorial on switch statement](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/switch.html).

Comment: Thanks for all of your answers! I had Java 7 installed but it was not associated with the workspace. I had an outdated version of Eclipse. For anyone reading this in the future, make sure you have Java 7 installed and previous versions of are Java wiped. Then, enable that version for your workspace.

Answer (score 3):

In addition to Nambari's answer: You can use if-else constructs with Strings, of course, to have a switch-like logic with Strings.

Answer (score 2):

Your code is right, but the String support for switch-case constructs were introduced in java7 (jdk1.7), so your error means that you have an older java version and you have to upgrade it.
If you don't want to upgrade your Java, then you'll need to use a multiple if-else construct:

```
[...]
if(VARIABLE.equals("start")){
    System.out.println("Machine started!");
} else if(VARIABLE.equals("stop")){
    System.out.println("Machine stopped!");
} else {
    System.out.println("Invalid command");
}
[...]
```